# Rolling 7 Day Count Distinct in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has 2 columns:
Date:  all dates from 1/1/16-12/31/16
ID:  unique identifier that is a text field.  Specific IDs may or may not occur across multiple days.

I want to count a rolling 7 day tally of distinct IDs for each day.  Here is SQL to do it for a single day:

1/7/16:

```
Select '2017-01-07' as week_end_date, count(distinct(id)) as ids
from table
where date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-07'
```

Rather than run the above query 365 times, once for each date, is there any way to do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting distinct ids is tricky.  If performance is not an issue, you can do:

```
Select week_start_date + interval '6 day' as week_end_date,
       count(distinct id) as ids
from table join
     generate_series('2016-01-01'::date, '2017-01-01'::date, interval '1 day') as g(week_start_date) 
where date between week_start_date and week_start_date + interval '6 day';
```

Comment: You are brilliant!  The only thing that is weird is that the date generated by the generate_series function comes back displayed weird.  For example:  

2017-07-18 20:00:00 

is what displays for the date '2017-07-19'.  It queries correctly, and it gives the right answer, but the format is off by 4 hours it appears.  

Is there a way to adjust that?

Comment: It's because the server is on GMT, but I'm pulling back the results to my laptop which is in EDT.  Problem solved!  Thanks again for your help Gordon!!

Comment: @Mark . . . You can add or subtract 4 hours from `g.dte`.